# Aussie visiting and re-visiting the UK visa-free

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, australian-citizens, repeat-visits

If I am an Australian entering the UK without a visa and I travel back and forth between EU and UK during the 6 months, will I be free to get another 6-month stay beyond the last day of the 6 month period? I have heard something like the limit for an Aussie without a visa in the UK is 6 months stay within any 12 months time-frame but I'm not sure if this is true? Ideally, I'm looking to be abroad for 12 months without a visa hopping between UK and EU/Africa - no work required. I just don't want to end up in immigration trouble.

Comment: How Long were you in the UK for in total? And how big will the gap be until you go back there?

Answer (score 0):

> I have heard something like the limit for an Aussie without a visa in the UK is 6 months stay within any 12 months time-frame but I'm not sure if this is true?

**It's not true**. Normally when entering without a visa for tourism or business, you get a 6-month leave, and technically there's no limit as to how many such admssions periods you can get within a certain timeframe.

However, if the officers suspect you're trying to live in the UK through visa runs, or perform an activity that requires a visa, they'll either give you a shorter leave to enter or refuse you entry.

If you stayed for several months and are returning less than a couple of months later, expect to be interrogated. In this case, **bring every single piece of evidence of ties to Australia, to present on request**